# Android:Storing username and password?

Tags: android

I want to make a special android app for a company. My purpose is that if users don't have email and password, they can register and then login
 or users have already have an account so they can login easily.
 I finished the design and code so far but I have a problem at this point: I don't know how and where to store users email and password? I need a file such as `'.ini'` or `'.conf'`, where to store users ınformation. Please guide me how to do this.

Comment: SharedPreferences ? ContentProvider ?

Comment: If you want to store permanent means you should use Shared Preference which is used by Facebook and Twitter SDK to store Access Token and Secret.

Comment: On the server perhaps ?